# If $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ are two bases for the same topology, then are $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ comparable?

Tags: general-topology

> **Question 1)**
>   I know that if $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal B'$ then $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$ but is the converse true? I.e. that if $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}} \subset \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$ then $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{B}'$.
>
> **Question 2)**
>   If $\mathcal{T}$ has two differents bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{ B'}$, then does it hold that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{B}'$ and $\mathcal{B}' \subset \mathcal{B}$?

I  use the notation $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{B}'$ to mean that if $B \in \mathcal{B}$ then there is $B' \in \mathcal{B}'$ such that $B'\subset B$.

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in your first question !

Comment: @PanchalShamsundar: why ? It may be $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B'}\subset \mathcal T_{\mathcal B}$ ?

Comment: @Peter indeed, I gave an example in my answer.

Comment: I  suggest you use a different notation, such as  $\mathcal B\leq^*\mathcal B'$ instead of  "$\subset$". It is better to invent a new notation than to use one that already has another common use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different notion of "smaller", that also takes points in consideration:

For families of subsets of $X$ we define: 
$$\mathcal{B} \le \mathcal{B}' \text{ iff } \forall B \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B: \exists B' \in \mathcal{B}': x \in B' \subseteq B$$

It's then easy to see that $\mathcal{B} \le \mathcal{B}'$ implies $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$ because each member of $\mathcal{B}$ is open under $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$.

From this it's easy to see that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$ also implies $\mathcal{B} \le \mathcal{B}'$. This implies a positive answer to the second question for this notion $\le$.

The OP's condition (I'll denote it $\le_P$ for Peter, say) 
$$\mathcal{B} \le_P \mathcal{B}' \text{ iff } \forall B \in \mathcal{B}: \exists B' \in \mathcal{B}': B' \subseteq B$$ does not necessarily imply that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}'}$. This can be seen from $\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b) : a < b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}' = \{(a,b): a < b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which obeys $\mathcal{B} \le_P \mathcal{B}'$ but the Sorgenfrey topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is strictly stronger (!) than the usual topology, which is generated by $\mathcal{B}'$.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you :) You look to be very good in topology, may be you can ask you something : If $\mathcal T\subset \mathcal T'$ and $\mathcal T$ is metrizable, will $\mathcal T'$ also metrizable ?

Comment: @Peter Glad to be able to help. No to your question. A topology that is finer than a metric one need not be metrisable (the same Sorgenfrey example), nor a coarser one either (e.g. the pointwise topology on $C([0,1])$ is weaker than the sup-metric one and non-metrisable.)

Comment: That's perfect :) Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Just by curiosity, I remarked that $\leq$ you defined is not an order on the set of the basis of $\mathcal T$ since it's not antisymetric (i.e. $\mathcal B\leq \mathcal B'$ and $\mathcal B'\leq \mathcal B$ doesn't implies that $\mathcal B=\mathcal B'$). Which type of relation is it ?

Comment: @Peter it’s often called a pre-order. Transitive and reflexive.